# Aggregate data based on a categorical variable

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to calculate mean salary for every job title from a data set which has 2159 job titles and convert into a list. My code

```
> for (i in 1:length(unique(sfs$JobTitle))) {
  a<-print(paste((sfs$JobTitle[[i]])))
  b<-print(paste((mean(sfs$BasePay[[i]]))))
  ms<-list(a,b)
}
```

Also tried

> ```
> for (i in 1:length(unique(sfs$JobTitle))) {   ms<-matrix((sfs$JobTitle[[i]]),(mean(sfs$BasePay[[i]]))) }
> ```

The output I am getting is a list of 2 elements only. Can you guys help. Thanks

Comment: and that output you are getting is for the last two only. If you are looking for mean  salary of all job titles, show us your data `head(dput(dataframename)`, there are faster ways out there

Comment: Seems like you need `aggregate(sfs$BasePay, list(sfs$JobTitle), mean)`.. but other than that, there are a lot of mistakes in your code. You don't have to use `paste` or `print` or `[[`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you don't need a for loop. There are other ways to do it. 
If you have a `data.frame` try this:

```
agg = aggregate(BasePay ~ JobTitle, data=sfs, mean)
```

This would work also:

```
sapply(split(sfs$BasePay, sfs$JobTitle), mean)
```

If you insist on having a list, use lapply:

```
lapply(split(sfs$BasePay, sfs$JobTitle), mean)
```